# iphone: QuartzCore and animations work in simulator but not in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, quartz-graphics

I currently have 3 simple UIImageViews that animate across a UIView in my app.

The animations work fine in the simulator.

However, when I test the app on the device, all I see is a blank UIView.

Are there any special libraries/header files I need to import to fix the problem of animation not appearing on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.. a background image had got saved on the simulator from an older version of the app but not added to the device.